# How to convert array of Integers to binary encoding in TensorFlow or Numpy?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

I have an input of numbers, ranging on `[0, 15]`, which I want to feed to my network as a binary code with 4 bits. For example, the input `[0,1,4,7]` should become `[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,1,0,0],[0,1,1,1]]`.

The `tf.one_hot` operation is close, but not exactly what I want. Is there any elegant way, either with Numpy or TensorFlow, to convert my input into its binary encoding, in order to feed it into my network?

My best solution was to use `np.binary_repr` for each value, and convert it from a `string` into an array of `integers`, but I feel this is not a good solution (converting twice, first into string, then into array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
np.unpackbits(np.array([[0,1,4,7]],np.uint8)).reshape(-1,4)[1::2,:]
```

I'm sure it can be refined but at least it's vectorized

Or this probably makes more sense:

```
np.unpackbits(np.array([[0,1,4,7]],np.uint8)).reshape(-1,8)[:,4:]
```

Comment: The second option seems much cleaner. Good job